# How can I change the flask limitter error page?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I use a flask limtter library in some places to avoid overcrowding. When there are too many requests, the page I throw below turns. I want to change this page. The code that returns this page is below.
[image]

```
"""
errors and exceptions
"""

from distutils.version import LooseVersion
from pkg_resources import get_distribution
from six import text_type
from werkzeug import exceptions

werkzeug_exception = None
werkzeug_version = get_distribution("werkzeug").version
if LooseVersion(werkzeug_version) < LooseVersion("0.9"):  # pragma: no cover
    # sorry, for touching your internals :).
    import werkzeug._internal
    werkzeug._internal.HTTP_STATUS_CODES[429] = 'Too Many Requests'
    werkzeug_exception = exceptions.HTTPException
else:
    # Werkzeug 0.9 and up have an existing exception for 429
    werkzeug_exception = exceptions.TooManyRequests


class RateLimitExceeded(werkzeug_exception):
    """
    exception raised when a rate limit is hit.
    The exception results in ``abort(429)`` being called.
    """
    code = 429
    limit = None

    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        if limit.error_message:
            description = limit.error_message if not callable(
                limit.error_message
            ) else limit.error_message()
        else:
            description = text_type(limit.limit)
        super(RateLimitExceeded, self).__init__(description=description)
```

Comment: this should get you going - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/

Comment: @noslenkwah thank you.